# Problem: Page is crashing and consuming a lot of memory after that (Blazor + EF 3.1.1)

Tags: entity-framework, blazor

I recently started to work with Blazor and Entity Framework and ran into a problem I don't know how to solve properly:

I use Blazor server + webassembly and code-first approach for DB.
I have 2 entities with relation one to many and want to load child object with parent included. If I get all child objects for a table, everything is fine; however, if I get only one child by using Where method with Include, app starts a recursion. It gets parent, then all its children, all their parents and so on, until I get "out of memory" exception in client app.

I turned on Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, and it helped me for table view, but it doesn't work for loading only one child.

Parent object:

```
public partial class Project
{
    public long ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Environment> Environments { get; set; }
}
```

Parent access layer:

```
public IEnumerable<Project> GetAllProjects()
{
    try
    {
        return _context.Projects.ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
        return new List<Project>();
    }
}
public Project GetProjectData(long id)
{
    try
    {
        Project project = _context.Projects.Find(id);
        return project;
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

Child object:

```
public partial class Environment
{
    public long EnvironmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Child access layer:

```
public IEnumerable<Environment> GetAllEnvironments() // this one works fine
{
    try
    {
        return _context.Environments
            .Include(e => e.Project)
            .ToList();
    }
    catch
    {
        return new List<Environment>();
    }
}

public Environment GetEnvironmentData(long id) // this one starts endless recursion
{
    try
    {
        Environment env = _context.Environments
            .Where(e => e.EnvironmentId == id)
            .Include(e => e.Project)
            .FirstOrDefault();
        return env;
    }
    catch { throw; }
}
```

For now I'm loading parent object manually, but it would be good to figure out how to do it automatically with Include.

Comment: Did you try to invert the where clause with the include ?

Comment: Yes, it didn't help

Comment: And if you do where -> toList -> firstOrDefault ?

Comment: I've tried that, but result is the same. First, I get "object reference is null" when @env.Project.Name is called on a page, but the page is still using CPU, and memory on a client is consumed in a geometric progression.

Comment: I've also tried to use Linq query with the same result. Query: 
Environment env = (from e in _context.Environments.Include("Project")
 where e.EnvironmentId == id
 select e).FirstOrDefault<Environment>();

Comment: I guess the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the solution was really simple, I didn't check for null for 'Project' property of 'Environment' object. After I added this check to the page problem is gone.

I'm still not sure why the page was consuming a lot of memory after it had encountered the 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' error.

```
@if (env == null || env.Project == null)
{
    <strong>Loading...</strong>
}
else
{
    // page markup
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Think about what you want the JSON to look like, and you'll see you need to break the cycle in your JSON serializer by [supressing](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) the serialization of one of the navigation properties, probably `Environment.Project`.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried it in both classes in Server project, and here are the results. If I add JsonIgnore to Project property in Environment.cs, it prevents table with Environments from loading. If I add JsonIgnore to Environments property in Project.cs, it doesn't change anything in my case, page still goes into endless recursion.

Comment: I downloaded the project and couldn't repro the error.  Are you sure this isn't a mis-diagnosis?  You're swallowing exceptions in some methods, which you should never do.

Comment: I know I haven't implemented normal exceptions handling yet, I'm just trying to focus on basic functionality now. This error appears when I try to delete Environment. I uploaded a screenshot here: https://github.com/Georgy-Sav/Blazor-EF-test/blob/master/Error.png

Comment: I've commented out all try catch blocks from both controllers in methods for getting data, but I still don't have any exceptions in terminal (I use VSCode), and page still falls into recursion. I don't have try catch in other related files

Comment: I'm not sure about a mis-diagnosis. I just guessed it based on memory consumption. Page is consuming memory in blocks, and each block is bigger then previous.

Comment: I reproduced it.  It appears to be a hang in blazor/web assembly, which is beyond my ability to debug.